# This SQL statement is not a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

So I deleted my last question related to this topic, as I think I have the logic worked out. But now when I try to build an SSIS package (or even just use Import/Export wizard) I get the following error

```
This sql statement is not a query
```

The code is as follows:

```
DECLARE @start int, @end int
DECLARE @start_ag int, @end_ag int
DECLARE @custID varchar(25)
DECLARE @custID_final varchar(25)
DECLARE @product varchar(50)
DECLARE @AgreementID int
DECLARE @dept varchar (5)
DECLARE @invDate datetime2
DECLARE @startDate datetime2
DECLARE @endDate datetime2

DECLARE @tempInvoices TABLE
(
ProductNumber varchar(15) not null,
CustomerID varchar(25) not null,
CustomerDept varchar (4) null,
InvoiceDate datetime2 not null,
AgreementID int null,
Quantity int not null,
InvoiceNumber varchar(25) not null,
RowNum int null
)

DECLARE @tempAgreements TABLE
(
AgreementID int,
RowNum int
)

INSERT INTO @tempInvoices
(RowNum, CustomerID, CustomerDept, ProductNumber, Quantity, InvoiceDate, InvoiceNumber)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY INVOICE) AS RowNum, Account, Dept, CustomerItem, Qty, InvoiceDate, Invoice
FROM [ensite].[dbo].[UI.CustomerInvoices]
where Suffix = 'GEP'
and InvoiceDate = CONVERT (date, GETDATE() - 1)
SET @custID_final = ''

SELECT @start = 1
SELECT @end = MAX(RowNum) FROM @tempInvoices
WHILE (@start <= @end)
BEGIN
    SELECT @custID = CustomerID from @tempInvoices where RowNum = @start 
    SELECT @dept = CustomerDept from @tempInvoices where RowNum = @start
    SELECT @product = ProductNumber from @tempInvoices where RowNum = @start
    SELECT @invDate = InvoiceDate from @tempInvoices where RowNum = @start
    BEGIN
        if @dept <> ''
            SET @custID_final = @custID + '-' + @dept
        else
            SET @custID_final = @custID
    END
    if @custID_final IN (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID From [CompuData].[PriceAgreements].[AgreementsCustomersPivot])
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @tempAgreements 
            (RowNum, AgreementID)
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AgreementID) AS RowNum, AgreementID 
            From [CompuData].[PriceAgreements].[AgreementsCustomersPivot] 
            WHERE CustomerID = @custID_final
            SELECT @start_ag = 1
            SELECT @end_ag = MAX(RowNum) FROM @tempAgreements
            WHILE (@start_ag <= @end_ag)
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @AgreementID = AgreementID FROM @tempAgreements WHERE RowNum = @start_ag
                    if @product IN (SELECT DISTINCT ProductNumber FROM [CompuData].[PriceAgreements].[AgreementsItemsPivot] WHERE AgreementID = @AgreementID)
                        BEGIN
                            SELECT @startDate = StartDate FROM [CompuData].[PriceAgreements].[PriceAgreemets] WHERE AgreementID = @AgreementID
                            SELECT @endDate = EndDate FROM [CompuData].[PriceAgreements].[PriceAgreemets] WHERE AgreementID = @AgreementID                      
                                if @invDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
                                    BEGIN
                                        UPDATE @tempInvoices
                                        SET AgreementID = @AgreementID
                                        WHERE RowNum = @start
                                        DELETE FROM @tempAgreements
                                        SELECT @start = @start + 1
                                    END
                                else
                                    BEGIN
                                        if @start_ag = @end_ag
                                        BEGIN
                                            DELETE FROM @tempInvoices where RowNum = @start
                                            SELECT @start = @start + 1
                                        END
                                    else
                                        BEGIN
                                            SELECT @start_ag = @start_ag + 1
                                        END
                                    END

                        END 
                    else
                        BEGIN
                                        if @start_ag = @end_ag
                                        BEGIN
                                            DELETE FROM @tempInvoices where RowNum = @start
                                            SELECT @start = @start + 1
                                        END
                                    else
                                        BEGIN
                                            SELECT @start_ag = @start_ag + 1
                                        END
                                    END
                END
        END
    else
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM @tempInvoices where RowNum = @start
            SELECT @start = @start + 1
        END
END

INSERT INTO [CompuData].[PriceAgreements].[AgreementsInvoicesPivot]
(CustomerID, AgreementID, ProductNumber, Quantity, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate)
SELECT CustomerID, AgreementID, ProductNumber, Quantity, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate
FROM @tempInvoices
```

Comment: Wait you're trying to run this in an SSIS package? If you are attempting to dump this much procedural code into an OLEDB source SQL statement you are using that tool incorectly. This is not a SQL statement it's about 20 SQL statements.

Comment: Noted. I'm unsure of how to migrate this data nightly otherwise. Thoughts Zane?

Comment: Well if you need to use this logic to move your data then turn this into a `INSERT` statement. Then insert this into what is often refered to as a staging table. Then you can select from that stage table and use SSIS to move the data wherever you need it to go. Truncate, rinse, repeat nightly. I don't know enough about your process to comment on the logic of the aformentioned SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be as follows - again, not knowing the full workflow, but this is the way I'd design it.

1. Create a package that first, using a Execute SQL Task, checks for the presence of the table [TempInvoices] and if doesn't exist (which it should not), creates it:

   IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TempInvoices]') AND type in (N'U'))
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[TempInvoices]
   GO

   CREATE TABLE [TempInvoices]
   (
   ProductNumber varchar(15) not null,
   CustomerID varchar(25) not null,
   CustomerDept varchar (4) null,
   InvoiceDate datetime2 not null,
   AgreementID int null,
   Quantity int not null,
   InvoiceNumber varchar(25) not null,
   RowNum int null
   )
2. Repeat step one, but for the [tempAgreements] table:

   IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TempAgreements]') AND type in (N'U'))
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[TempAgreements]
   GO

   CREATE TABLE [TempAgreements]
   (
   AgreementID int,
   RowNum int
   )
3. Setup a Data Flow task to populate your tables.  You can add the query language that you have included as part of the SQL Query used to get the OLE DB data source.  Make sure to set the "Delay Validation" to True in the properties.
4. Follow the directions of @Zane and take these staging tables to setup some additional queries needed for subsequent Data Flow tasks.  It looks like there are multiple paths in your code, based on a few values in your staging tables, so there may be multiple roads down the package.
5. Finally, setup a final Data Flow task to populate your [AgreementsInvoicesPivot] table.

This is how I would envision building it - hope this helps.

Comment: No problem.  Post any questions back here.  Once you figure out the process, since it's an Integration Services package, you can setup a SQL Agent Job to run overnight, or on your schedule.